# Global Timer i.e. A Timer which works on multiple forms. - C#

Tags: c#, forms, timer, controls

I was wondering if it would be possible to create a timer which isnt bound to a single form. Basically im making a quiz and i want the user to only have 2 minutes to answer all questions. Once the 2 minutes are up the current form will close and an endscreen will appear. The time must also be visible at all times. Any help would be great.

Comment: How about a keep static variable and updating timer on every form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use a static class with a static dispatch timer.

```
public static class StaticTimer`
{
   public static DispatcherTimer timer { get; set; }
}
```

In Form Use:

```
StaticClass.timer = new DispatcherTimer();
StaticClass.timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100);
StaticClass.timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
StaticClass.timer.Start();

 public void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     logic....

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static timer. The timer can be accessed from all forms. Just update the time based on the static timer on each form.